# time conversion based on country_name/country_code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to get my head around this problem but even after doing lot of research I wasn't able to get a proper solution.

I'm trying to build a flight booking system. I've have an api which returns me the arrival and departure time of flights in UTC time. Now I want to show the departure and arrival time of the flight in the local time of that country. Is there any faster way to do this. So far I have got this thing working which seems quite heavy. I'm writing some sample code below.

```
<% flights.each do |flight| %>
  <% time_zone_name = TZInfo::Country.get(flight.departure_country_code).zone_names.first %>
  <% time_zone = TZInfo::Timezone.get('time_zone_name') %>
  departure_time : <%= time_zone.utc_to_local(flight.departure_time) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help. You can get the user's time zone and Time#localtime will give you the time in the current time zone of the machine running the code

```
> time = Time.now.utc
   => 2013-11-11 14:42:49 UTC 
> time.localtime
  => 2013-11-11 20:12:49 +0530
```